# How does MaybeReadByte's use of channels provide "random" behavior in Go?

Tags: go

In Prime function in Go's `crypto/rand` package (generates probable primes), it calls the `MaybeReadByte` function from the `crypto/internal/randutil` package (shown below). Based on the function description, I can understand why it's used, but I don't understand how this implementation has a 50% chance of reading the byte. Shouldn't one of the `case`s be guaranteed to run before the other?

```golang
var (
    closedChanOnce sync.Once
    closedChan     chan struct{}
)

// MaybeReadByte reads a single byte from r with ~50% probability. This is used
// to ensure that callers do not depend on non-guaranteed behaviour, e.g.
// assuming that rsa.GenerateKey is deterministic w.r.t. a given random stream.
//
// This does not affect tests that pass a stream of fixed bytes as the random
// source (e.g. a zeroReader).
func MaybeReadByte(r io.Reader) {
    closedChanOnce.Do(func() {
        closedChan = make(chan struct{})
        close(closedChan)
    })

    select {
    case <-closedChan:
        return
    case <-closedChan:
        var buf [1]byte
        r.Read(buf[:])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't one of the cases be guaranteed to run before the other?

No.

[Per the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.

Since both `case`s read the same channel, they are always both able to proceed at the same time.

Comment: The behavior is there to produce a modicum of scheduling fairness, and to avoid livelocks (imagine if you had deterministic `select` and the first case for `<-foo` always sent a new item on `foo`). Using it as a source of nondeterminism in the crypto library is... novel. :)